# Problem passing parameter to javascript function called from Lua using Fengari-Web

Tags: javascript, lua

I'm trying to call a javascript function with a single parameter from Lua using Fengari, but the parameter value is always undefined.

The following code correctly invokes the "display" function but the argument (64) is not correctly passed into the function, and "digit" is always undefined. Could anyone advise please?

```
const lua = fengari.lua;
const lauxlib = fengari.lauxlib;
const lualib = fengari.lualib;
const interop = fengari.interop;

function display(digit) {
    console.log(`digit is ${digit}`);
}

let L = lauxlib.luaL_newstate();
lualib.luaL_openlibs(L);
interop.luaopen_js(L);

interop.push(L,display);
lua.lua_setglobal(L,fengari.to_luastring("display"));

const result = lauxlib.luaL_dostring(L, fengari.to_luastring('display(64)'));

if (result !== lua.LUA_OK) {
    // Error occurred
    const errorMessage = lua.lua_tostring(L, -1);
    console.error("Lua error:", fengari.to_jsstring(errorMessage));
    lua.lua_pop(L, 1);
} else {
    // Execution was successful
    console.log("Lua code executed successfully");
}
```

Comment: All functions exported from JS to Lua follow colon syntax in Lua expressions (that is, they always have "self" argument).  So, try `display(nil,64)`.